# How do I write and compile Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, linux, clang

How do I write and compile Objective-C code in Linux?

I heard about Clang, but I couldn't find any example/tutorial about Clang/LLVM/Objective-C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Game programming on Objective-C and linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447942/game-programming-on-objective-c-and-linux)

Comment: @Kay I wouldn't close this as a duplicate, because the other question has only pre-clang/llvm answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gobjc gobjc++ gnustep gnustep-devel libgnustep-base-dev -y
vi *.m
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` *.m -lgnustep-base -lobjc
```

Answer (score 11):

You download and build LLVM as the compiler infrastructure; then you download and build the CLANG front-end to compile C/C++ and Objective C/C++.

I guess you could try following this [quick start](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) guide. Mind that Clang could actually replace GCC when working with these languages.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.gnustep.org/ they have tools for developing with Objective-C 2.0 for LINUX. The source files and hints on how to install it on several LINUX distros are here: http://www.gnustep.org/resources/sources.html

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following script shown on this page:

https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/5652802

Pay attention: During the first compiling process you will get an error. Solution is just to recompile it... It works !!! Here is the blog entry from the step by step installation but I really recommend the script!

http://blog.tlensing.org/2013/02/24/objective-c-on-linux-setting-up-gnustep-clang-llvm-objective-c-2-0-blocks-runtime-gcd-on-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-54284

regards