# How to run Objective C program on fedora?

Tags: objective-c, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Game programming on Objective-C and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447942/game-programming-on-objective-c-and-linux)

Hi i am new to objective C and i dont have mac machine to run objective C program. I googled alot for the commands and solutions to run but i didnt get any  thing. Can any suggest me any solution to run objective C program on fedora along with commands.

Any help is appricated.

Thanks

Comment: Gcc can compile Objective-c, but you will not be able to make iOS apps, since you can't install the SDK.

Comment: You need a Mac to program for MacOS and iOS. For learning purpose, you can try [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/), but that's not recommended, a Mac is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for rly. I have installed GCC. Can you provide me commands to comiple and run programs

Answer (score 0):

[Programming in Objective-C by Stephen Kochan](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Objective-C-Automatic-Reference-Developers/dp/0321811909/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1350035430&sr=8-1) Has a couple of chapters at the start of the book that show how to compile Objective-C programs from the command line using GCC.

The updated edition may have been updated to replace GCC with LLVM, but I haven't read those yet.